# In Azure, what is the difference between the two Data Science Virtual Machines for Windows?

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-dsvm

I am provisioning a new VM for Windows to run some samples using Python notebooks and sql server. The [existing samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-data-science-provision-vm) are using the classic portal. In the new portal, I have the options to add or provision one of two VMs:

- Data Science Virtual Machine runs on Windows
- Data Science Virtual Machine runs on Windows (CSP)

I want to know the difference; I might be misreading it, it seems one has license (CSP's description says "Bring Your Own License enabled.")? Also, When should one pick one over the other?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/hybridcloudbp/2016/03/04/microsoft-azure-and-csp/) is helpful to you.

Comment: If  you select 1, Azure will provide the license  for services on it. If you select 2, you need to purchase the license for 3rd party Marketplace software somewhere else, and then use it for the 3rd party service, deployed in Azure.

Comment: Thanks, seems like CSP is a program you need to be enrolled? If I chose 1, do I get dev licenses or how does it work for them to provide licenses?

Comment: Would like to know why the down vote.

Comment: If you select 1, you also need SQL server license.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT but you mentioned "If you select 1, Azure will provide the license for services on it."

Comment: Costs seem to be same in general https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-au/marketplace/apps/microsoft-ads.standard-data-science-vm?tab=PlansAndPrice. I already pinged azure support to get more details. Thanks a lot Walter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSP editions of the Data Science Virtual Machine (#DSVM) are only deployable in CSP (Cloud Solution Provider) based subscriptions. CSPs are Microsoft Partner companies that are certified to re-sell Microsoft cloud services and provide value added services on top.

Here's a comparison of the different licensing modes that are available:
[Licensing Modes for Cloud Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRHD4.png)

If you are not using a CSP subscription you deploy the non CSP offers. As the CSP offers require the licenses to be provided by a CSP and on a CSP Licensing Agreement.

Comment: I took the non CSP and seems to be provisioned with licenses so they probably use dev licenses (although most stuff there is open sourced). Is that right?

Comment: Actually both versions have Dev Licenses for the MS tools and accompanying tools from the open source community. The only difference being the channel through which the service is purchased. In CSP you purchase the services through a 3rd party who is a registered Microsoft partner and in many cases they may adjust pricing etc. to account for other added services that they may provide on top. Many customers use this model. In any other licensing mode, you are purchasing the service directly from Microsoft as explained in the picture link of my last answer.

Comment: P.S. We are active working on bringing out DSVM versions with Enterprise/Production ready licenses and you should see them in the near future. With the Dev licenses of products like SQL Server and Microsoft R Server, users are limited  to only working with non production Data. We have had significant interest from our users to use Production Data on the DSVMs.